# Passing value from parent to child component, where child is nested within a tabpanel of a tabview

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, tabpanel

As stated in the question, the child component is nested in the tab panel defined in the parent component. Since it is a tabview, I can have multiple tab panels within that, which would mean multiple child component with the child nested in the tab panel. I would like to set a value in the child component based on the tab panel that is active. But regardless of the tab that I am in, the only value that gets set is that of tab 0. To explain better, here is a trimmed down prototype of the existing code. I have a working example set up here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fd7b3j

Click 'Create Tabs' to create a few tabs. Make Tab 3 the current tab. Click 'Add One'. Expected outcome is that element value would get updated to 4, but instead, the element value in Tab 0 gets updated to 1. How do I redirect the action to the correct tab? Is that even possible?

app.component.html

```
<p-button label="Create Tabs" (onClick)="handleClick()"></p-button>
<p-button label="AddOne" (onClick)="AddOne()"></p-button>
<p-tabView (onChange)=setIndex($event) [(activeIndex)]="index">
  <p-tabPanel #panel [header]="elememt" *ngFor="let elememt of counterList; let i = index" [selected]="i == currentIndex" >
    <app-main #main [element]="counterList[i]"></app-main>
  </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';
import { TabViewNav, TabView } from 'primeng/tabview';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'tabViews';
  currentIndex = 0;
  @ViewChild('main') main: MainComponent;

  @ViewChild ('panel') panel: TabView;
  counter = 0;
  counterList: number[] = [];

  index = 0;

  handleClick(event: Event) {
      this.counterList = [...this.counterList, this.counter];

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.index = this.counter;
        this.currentIndex = this.counter;
        this.counter = this.counter + 1;
    }, 100);
  }

  setIndex(event) {
    this.currentIndex = event.index;
  }

  AddOne() {
    console.log(this.index);
    this.main.element = this.main.element + 1;
  }
}
```

main.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() element: number;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

main.component.html

```
{{element}}
```

Comment: can you explain bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that happened, becouse you used ViewChild, which gaves you just 1 reference to firs component. Now just use  ViewChildren for geting arrey of your child components and then you can call each of them by currentIndex. All you have to do that fix currentIndex, it mast change by onChage action of tab view. Enjoy it :))))

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewChildren, QueryList  } from '@angular/core';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';
import { TabViewNav, TabView } from 'primeng/tabview';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'tabViews';
  currentIndex = 0;
  @ViewChildren('main') main: QueryList<MainComponent>;

  @ViewChild ('panel') panel: TabView;
  counter = 0;
  counterList: number[] = [];

  tabIndex = 0;

  handleClick(event: Event) {
      this.counterList = [...this.counterList, this.counter];
      setTimeout(() => {
      this.currentIndex = this.counter;
      this.counter = this.counter + 1;     
     }, 100);
  }

  AddOne() {
    console.log(this.tabIndex);
   this.main.toArray()[this.currentIndex].element = this.main.toArray()[this.currentIndex].element  + 1;
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you Qarun, I tried the solution, but _results seems to be private attribute, it is not accessible, unless I need to be doing something more..

Comment: I'd like to help you  with reason of the problem in you situation. Small details like _result you can fix yourself, just use this.main.toArray(). It's weel be ok :))))

Comment: please don't forget that you need to realize changing currentIndex due to onChange tabs actions when you click them as well.

Comment: That was it Qarun!! I had tried setting up as ViewChildren before,  but did not know how to access the _results, so reverted back all my changes. The toArray() was the key. It has given me a heartburn for a few days now. The only change I would make to your answer is that the ```@ViewChildren('main') main: MainComponent;``` should be ```@ViewChildren('main') main: QueryList<MainComponent>; ``` then I can access the right element as ```this.main.toArray()[this.currentIndex]```. Could you please update your answer and I will accept it?

Comment: Of course, I can. The main point here is that it was helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

change implementation of AddOne like this

```
AddOne() {
    this.counterList[this.currentIndex]++;
}
```

Comment: Andrei, thanks for the solution, this is a working solution, but I needed more in line of what Quran suggested due to the way my existing code is set up.